# Why calling an OpenCV function in a loop becomes faster after the first call?

Tags: c++, opencv, benchmarking

I'm using `connectedComponents` function from OpenCV in a for loop like this:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

void cpuCCL(int i)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("test-ccl-"+std::to_string(i)+".png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::threshold(image, image, 150, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    if (!image.isContinuous()) {
        std::cerr << "Image is not allocated with continuous data. Exiting..." << std::endl;
    }

    int nccomps = -1;
    cv::Mat labels;

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    nccomps = connectedComponents(image, labels);
    auto finish = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    double elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<
        std::chrono::duration<double>>(finish - start).count();
    std::cout << "CPU code ran in: " << elapsed_seconds * 1000 << "ms\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of components (CPU): " << nccomps - 1 << "\n" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{         
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        cpuCCL(i);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output, I'm getting in my PC:

```
CPU code ran in: 22.938ms

Number of components (CPU): 4

CPU code ran in: 0.1271ms

Number of components (CPU): 4

CPU code ran in: 0.0653ms

Number of components (CPU): 4

CPU code ran in: 0.0867ms

Number of components (CPU): 4

CPU code ran in: 0.0824ms

Number of components (CPU): 4

CPU code ran in: 0.0826ms

Number of components (CPU): 4

CPU code ran in: 0.0835ms

Number of components (CPU): 4

CPU code ran in: 0.087ms

Number of components (CPU): 4

CPU code ran in: 0.0827ms

Number of components (CPU): 4

CPU code ran in: 0.0654ms

Number of components (CPU): 4
```

The thing is that, after the first call, that takes around 23 ms, the `connectedComponents` becomes two orders of magnitude faster. Note that images are identical. I cannot figure it why it becomes much faster, or I'm doing something wrong here to benchmark it. I can provide my image files if you want to try it.

Comment: You're compiling with optimization enabled, right?  Could the compiler be hoisting some of the work out of the loop, maybe even letting data on the GPU get reused?

Comment: Either that or lazy init of something some libraries use, like threads and GPU driver stuff?  Maybe `strace ./a.out` to see what system calls it makes, see if there are some that only happen inside the first timed region.

Comment: CPUs contain cache. that's a possible factor. -- and yes it might be using the GPU transparently. OpenCV uses OpenCL a lot. such usage requires some initialization.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Well, it seems it’s not just the first iteration, cause the second iteration takes around 0.12 ms but after that it never exceeds 0.1 ms, so it seems still something is going on after the first iteration as well.

Comment: frequency scaling (of CPU?) in response to continued system load, though I think some modern CPUs just stay at a high frequency all the time, switch on/off in response to demand, and *throttle down* under sustained load to maintain TDP -- simply expect such effects and discard the first few measurements, and calculate time interval over several iterations (don't sum the runs, take time twice)